# CoreData disappearance of relationship after saving problem

Tags: macos, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a to-many relationship in my CoreData model without an inverse relationship which causes some strange behaviours.

For example: Entity of type A has a to-many relationship to an entity of type B. There is no inverse relationship from B to A. Now when I connect objects of type A with some objects of type B there is no problem. But after saving the whole management object context and restarting the application, the connections between the objects are no longer there except for one object (which has still the relationship). It can happen that different objects of type A has a relationship to one specific entity of type B - so they are sharing the same object.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that you don't actually have a to-many relationship set but rather a to-one. You just save the last B you set. I would log the relationship immediately before saving to confirm whether only one B is set.

Alternatively, without a reciprocal relationship, it is possible for an object to disappear from the graph without producing an error. If B has no relationship to A that means that B is not observing A and doesn't care what happens to it. You may be altering the graph without being aware. Delete rules can also cause odd behavior in this circumstance.

You should only use relationships without inverses in very rare cases. The inverse relationships help maintain the integrity of the object graph and prevents orphaned or disappearing objects.

Comment: Good points, I've checked the relationship and there is of course a to-many relationship between those entities. One note: the relationships don't disappear after saving the object context. Only after a restart of the app the relationships are gone!

Comment: I've fixed the problem by adding an inverse relationship! Thanks